# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Class Name'

Tags: core-data, ios6, restkit, restkit-0.20

I was trying to use CoreData along with RestKit 0.20.0 i got CoreData error.

//  Response.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Response : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * responseCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * responseMsg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * error;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * statisticsDetails;

@end
```

and Implementaion file is

//  Response.m

## import "Response.h"

```
@implementation Response

@dynamic error;
@dynamic responseCode;
@dynamic responseMsg;
@dynamic statisticsDetails;
@dynamic status;

@end
```

and my ViewController code is

//  ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "StatisticsDetails.h"
#import "TopProjects.h"
#import <RestKit.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mylocalUrl.com/Port"]];

/*managed object model */
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
 NSLog(@"managed object model: %@", managedObjectModel);

/* managed object store */
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
NSLog(@"managed object store: %@", managedObjectStore);

/* persistent store*/
NSError *error;
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
if (error) {
        NSLog(@"unresolved error , ");
     NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
   
}

/* managed object contexts*/


[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

/* entity mapping */

RKEntityMapping *responseEntityMapping =[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Response" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[responseEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"status" : @"status",
 @"responseCode":@"responseCode",
 @"responseMsg":@"responseMsg",
 @"error":@"error",
 @"statisticsDetails":@"statisticsDetails"
 }];

RKResponseDescriptor *ResponseDescriptor = [ RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseEntityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"getStatistics/4" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
          /* NSLog(@"mapping result: %d", [mappingResult array].count);
   
     NSLog(@"Mapping Result: %@", mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);     
}];
```

Error is

```
2013-07-12 12:35:09.098 Dashboard[85919:5403] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'ResponseClas'
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're creating your `RKObjectManager` instance but you don't provide it with a reference to your `managedObjectStore`, this is most likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore; is this line you speaking about?. 
If not please help me.